# Postgresql JSON Sql coding

Tags: json, postgresql

How to write JSON SQL coding for the below json data:

```
{
   "orderSystem":"SAP",
   "orderHeader":{
      "salesDoc":"0011214280",
      "soldTo":"0000089890",
      "createDate":"2020-01-02",
      "purchNo":"2020-00-16213",
      "billingStatus":"billed",
      "ecomStatus":"Complete/Invoiced",
      "purchDate":"2020-01-02",
      "netValHd":"33416.500000000",
      "taxesHd":"0.000000000",
      "currency":"USD"
   },
   "orderItems":[
      {
         "docNumber":"0011214280",
         "itmNumber":"000100",
         "netValue":"33416.500000000",
         "currency":"USD",
         "shipments":[
            {
               "docNumber":"0011214280",
               "itmNumber":"000100",
               "scheduleLine":"0001",
               "material":"000000000016121362"
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
   "invoices":[
      {
         "billingDoc":"0048471944",
         "docCategory":"M",
         "currency":"USD",
         "status":"CLOSED",
         "invoiceUrl":"/ZSD_BILLING_API_GET_PDF"
      }
   ]
}
```

Here "orderSystem":"SAP" is hard coded value. Then all "orderHeader" tags are from sales_order table. "orderItems" tags from sales_order_item table. "shipments" are from sales_order_shipment table. "invoices" are from invoice table.

sales_order table have single record for an order.
sales_order_item table may have multiple records for an order.
sales_order_shipment table may have multiple records for an order.
invoices table may have multiple records for an order.

Here joining column for all table is "salesDoc" column. How to achieve it sql json query?
Example i am giving input as salesDoc data. Then i need to pull the data in the above json format.

Comment: If I understood you well, you have some tables and now you want an output from them in the given json format?

Comment: Yes. You are right. @AfsharMohebi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer,

```
select row_to_json(tab)
from (
  select 'SAP' sourceSystem,
    (
      select row_to_json(od)
      from (
        select sales_order_header.salesDoc,sales_order_header.soldTo,sales_order_header.createDate,sales_order_header.purchNo,sales_order_header.billingStatus,sales_order_header.ecomStatus,sales_order_header.purchDate,sales_order_header.netValHd,sales_order_header.taxesHd,sales_order_header.currency
      ) od
    ) as orderHeader,
    (select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(li))) from (
            select sales_order_line.docNumber,sales_order_line.itmNumber,sales_order_line.netValue,sales_order_line.currency from 
            ecommerce.sales_order_line sales_order_line where sales_order_header.sales_ordr_no = sales_order_line.sales_ordr_no) li )as orderItems,
    (select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(ss))) from (
            select shipment.docNumber,shipment.itmNumber,shipment.scheduleLine,shipment.material
            from ecommerce.sales_order_shipment shipment where sales_order_header.sales_ordr_no = sales_order_shipment.sales_ordr_no) ss )as shipments,
    (select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(iv))) from (
            select invoices.billingDoc,invoices.docCategory,invoices.currency ,invoices.status, invoices.invoiceUrl
            from ecommerce.sales_order_invoices invoices where sales_order_header.sales_ordr_no = invoices.sales_ordr_no) iv )as invoices,
    
    from ecommerce.sales_order_header as sales_order_header
        
) tab
```

I went through the below link and it was very useful for my case

https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql